# Reading first item in serialized JSON

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I am trying to get name from first item in deserialized JSON object. 
When I debugged code, I found that jsonObject is converted to dictionary. 
How can I get first item value from jsonObject.

```
var myJson= [
{name:'abc',city:'dallas'},
{name:'def',city:'redmond'},
{name:'ghi',city:'bellevue'},
]

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObject = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(myJson);

NameInFirstItem = jsonObject[0].name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `class` to hold your resulting object:

```
public class MyJsonResult
{
    public string name { set; get; }
    public string result { set; get; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myJson = "[{ name: 'abc',city: 'dallas'},{ name: 'def',city: 'redmond'},{ name: 'ghi',city: 'bellevue'}]";

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<MyJsonResult> jsonResultList = jss.Deserialize<List<MyJsonResult>>(myJson);

    var NameInFirstItem = jsonResultList.FirstOrDefault().name;
}
```

**Or if you insist on using dynamic:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string myJson = "[{ name: 'abc',city: 'dallas'},{ name: 'def',city: 'redmond'},{ name: 'ghi',city: 'bellevue'}]";

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonResultList = jss.Deserialize<List<dynamic>>(myJson);

    // get first value by key from the dictionary
    var NameInFirstItem = jsonResultList.FirstOrDefault()["name"];
}
```

I prefer the first method. If you add a third property to your json, you might get confused with type of the generated object, which is probably a list of key-value pairs for each object in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var NameInFirstItem = jsonObject[0]["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize the json with

```
     public class Details
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
        }

  var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Details[]>(json);
  var name = res[0].name;
```